# problem with enabling remote management of hyper-v server 2008 r2

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, remote-access

I just recently installed hyper-v server 2008 r2 on a dedicated server i have, but i'm having trouble enabling remote management.

Running the HVRemote - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote - tool seems to have yielded some positive results, and all tests on the server pass (firewall, permissions, etc), but client-side things are not working. I'm stuck at this step :

5: - Simple query to root\cimv2 WMI namespace
     FAIL - Simple query failed
Cannot perform simple query against root\cimv2

Anyone could help me figure this out? I'm almost giving up and installing XenServer...

Thanks

Comment: What a coincidence! I just installed one and having similar problem. Are you on workgroup or domain?

Comment: workgroup.. I heard that doing this is a breeze in a domain environment... what a sad move by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out what was happening.. In my case both client and server are **not** part of a domain, and I am connecting over the internet.

The name you connect to in HyperV manager must be **the same** as the name you configured your server in "System Properties" (option 2 in sconfig on hyper-v server 2008 r2).

Example:
 Your server is called "SERVER" and is accessible over the internet via server.mydomain.com - when connecting you must only use "SERVER" in the connection profile.

Unless both server and client are on the same network, this is not going to work, so you will have to add an entry on your HOSTS file pointing "SERVER" to the real IP address of the server.

That did the trick for me. Hope it helps someone!