# Issue when connecting to Hyper-V Server 2012 throw Hyper-V manager(Windows7) and Powershell

Tags: hyper-v, wmi, rpc

I know there is many topic, but i cannot find solution that works. There is issue when connecting to hyper-v server throw hyper-v manager and also powershell.

```
Can not connect to RPC service.
```

According this [problem with enabling remote management of hyper-v server 2008 r2](https://serverfault.com/questions/215190/problem-with-enabling-remote-management-of-hyper-v-server-2008-r2) client machine and server must have same domain.
Is there some method to include them?

My creditials(user, password) on server side and client are same
RPC, WMI, Net bios services are also runing.

Evoluting hvremote as diagnostic tools shows next information:

```
C:\>cscript hvremote.wsf /show /target:HYPERSERV 
2) ping attempt (ping -4 -n -1 HYPERSERV)
Note the ping may timeout -that is OK. However, if you get an error that HYPERSERV could not be found, you need to fix DNS or add an entry to the hosts file. Test 3 will fail and provide more guidance.

3) Connect to root\cimv2 WMI namespace
*** Failed to connect to root\cimv2
*** Error: -214023174 Server RPC not evailable.
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you have is that Hyper-V manager on Windows 7 And Windows Server 2008 R2 cannot manage Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012. You need to use Hyper-V Manager from Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8.

Comment: My remote admin manage Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012. May be need additional information? Systeminfo log ?

Comment: Are you sure he isn't establishing an RDP session directly to the Windows Server 2012 machine and running Hyper-V manager locally?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're running a workgroup since you ask how to include the server and client in the same domain. To do that you need to setup a domain controller and join the computers to the domain. I won't touch that subject since there's plenty of info on the internet about it.

If you want to remote manage your hyper-v server without running a domain (using a workgroup) you must:

On the server:

1. open up the firewall for incoming WMI management
2. create a user account with same name/password as you use on the client computer
3. give your user account dcom remote launch permission
4. give your user account access to the wmi-namespaces cimv2 and virtualization
5. give your user account a role in hyper-v:s local role store, which you access through azman.msc and point it to the c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\hyper-v\initialstore.xml

On the client:

1. give the built-in account “anonymous logon” remote dcom launch permission

One problem in using a normal account on the server is that wmi scripts that need to be run with administrator permissions must be run under the built-in administrator account, not a regular account in the administrators group since accounts are not elevated by the wmi script engine and will fail instead.

Microsofts guide:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794756

I wrote a small blog explanation regarding Server 2012
http://blog.plausibledeniability.se/post/33464344054/hyper-v-remote-administration

If you want to use powershell you must also make the client trust the server by running
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="SERVERHOSTNAME"}'

edit: I'm unsure if you can remote from a Windows 7 host at all, haven't tried or googled it.

Comment: By the way if tcp/udp 135 port is closed, can be succesfull RPC connection?

Comment: @Stepchik Normally not since the RPC Endpoint Mapper is accessed over tcp 135 by default and that's the way the client finds the service. But there's rpc over https and such so it's certainly possible.

Comment: I can successfully access only if my client machine and server have one hosting provider.